# InstantiateViewController resulting a nil causing it to crash

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

**What I'm trying to do:**

I am trying to press a + button on the top right side of the navigation bar, push the app to a new view (using navigationController.pushViewController), get some user input text from the new view, then return back to the original view.

[image]

**Problem:**

Below code returns nil, which causes the navigationController.pushViewController to crash the app.
So again, I do

```
let newPostView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PostNewActivityViewController") as? PostNewActivityViewController
```

then the line below crashes the app, because the newPostView is nil.

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(newPostView!, animated: true)
```

And all the error message I get from this exception is EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION and the console output is only telling me that it unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. I don't understand why newPostView is nil.

Also, I am wondering if this is the best practice to obtain user input from another view controller.

Any help or feedback will be much appreciated.

Comment: check if the you actually set the controller `storyboard id`, or if the controller is associated to `PostNewActivityViewController` class

Comment: Use the UIStoryboard instead.

Comment: @matt, are you mad, man? Figure it out for yourself?!?! That's what the internet is for!

Comment: @Lamar Just did a p self.storyboard and it came out as nil. Is this because I don't have a storyboard scene for it? 
I never used storyboard before, as I learned everything to be done in programmatically thus far.

Comment: @matt I have debugged this for some time and I am fairly new to Swift programming. I couldn't figure it out even after hours of searching, so I came here to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment, you mention that `p self.storyboard` (in the debugger) is producing (printing) `nil`.

So I suggest you get a reference to the Storyboard in the following way instead:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YOUR STORYBOARD'S NAME (e.g. Main)", bundle: Bundle.main)
```

And then proceed to instantiate and present your `UIViewController` in the same way, like this:

```
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PostNewActivityViewController")
present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So far I didn't even touch the storyboard and the there are only two default ones (Main.storyboard and LaunchScreen.storyboard).
I did try your suggestion, and it crashed in AppDelegate with the following reason:
'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x600000471740>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'PostNewActivityViewController''

Comment: Okay, and the Storyboard containing the PostNewActivityViewController is definitely the same one (Main)? Also, check that you have set the PostNewActivityViewController's Storyboard ID to "PostNewActivityViewController"

Comment: I ended up solving the problem other way around, as this solution requires me to use the storyboard which I did not use at all. But thank you though!